# SELECT query with COUNT and HAVING BY

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I modify the below query to **limit the number of rows fetched PER `userid` from the `post_list` table** without affecting the performance of the script (the post_list table is over 10,000 rows here) ?

```
$sql = query("SELECT userid, post, post_id, id, username 
FROM post_list, users
WHERE post_list.userid = users.id AND post_id%4 = 0 
ORDER BY post_id");
```

I need to have **5 posts MAX per post_list.userid.**

So if i have 10 users in my post_list table , the query will return 50 rows.

***EDIT:***

**USERS table**

```
  id        username
   1          bill
   2          mark
   3          kate
```

**POST_LIST table**

```
 post_id    userid    post 
   1           1       foo
   2           3       bar
   3           3       baz
   4           1       qux
   5           1       foo_1
   6           1       bar_1
   7           1       baz_1
   8           1       qux_1
```

Here, the query should only return 5 posts from Bill.

Also, i need the overall number of rows to be limited to 50.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT pl.*, u.*
FROM users AS u
JOIN (
    SELECT 
        userid,
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(post_id ORDER BY post_id DESC), ',', 5) AS last_5_posts
    FROM post_list
    GROUP BY userid
) AS pl5 ON(u.id = pl5.userid)
JOIN post_list AS pl ON (FIND_IN_SET(pl.post_id, pl5.last_5_posts))
ORDER BY pl.post_id DESC
LIMIT 50
```

Example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/36f12/30

Comment: +1 can you please tell what this line SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(post_id ORDER BY post_id DESC), ',', 5) does?

Comment: `GROUP_CONCAT - concat all post_id per user (99,36,22,21,19,14,2)
SUBSTRING_INDEX - take the first 5 ids (99,36,22,21,19)`

Comment: +1 it works ! how can i make sure the overall order is by post_id DESC (for instance, in the sqlfiddle, the result order should start with qux_1, then baz_1 etc) ?

Comment: I edited my post, but can't edit example in sqlfriddle because site is down :)

Answer (score 4):

Use [`LIMIT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html)

```
ORDER BY post_id LIMIT 5;
```

---

As you commented, you can take a look at this article [here](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/) which will explain you in detail, *How to select the first/least/max row per group in SQL*.

Comment: Would that only return 5 rows total?  I think he is looking for groups of 5 per user id

Comment: if i add LIMIT 5; i end up with the 5 last posts that were saved in the table. I need to SELECT the last 5 posts PER user.

Comment: @ChHr than you need http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by group by and count. Please try this query.

```
$sql = query("SELECT userid, post, post_id,username, wish_likes FROM post_list, 
users WHERE post_list.userid = users.id AND post_id%4 = 0 group by userid,post,   
 post_id,username, wish_likes having 
count(post_id) <= 5 ORDER BY post_id");
```

Comment: +1 Thanks, i forgot to mention: how can I limit the overall number of rows returned ? If i have 100 users, this query would fetch 500 results. I'd to limit the overall result to 50 rows.

Comment: for overall limiting rows we have to  use limit at the end of query but it depends how many number of rows or users you want your query to select.

Comment: i've tried this query several time, and yet it doesn't work. It doesn't limit the number of rows per userid, it fetches them all.

Comment: What is the issue you are facing. can you post table structure. do one thing please. try this. "SELECT userid FROM post_list, 
users WHERE post_list.userid = users.id AND post_id%4 = 0 group by userid having 
count(post_id) <= 5 ORDER BY post_id"

Comment: limit the number of columns in select and in group by then try it directly in phpmyadmin

Comment: See question, i edited it to make it clearer. With the query you wrote, i still get more than 5 rows per users.